# SwiftUI `swipeActions` and `confirmationDialog` delete the wrong item

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to use iOS 15.0 `swipeActions` and `confirmationDialog` to delete an item in a `List`.

But what happens is that the wrong item gets deleted.

Here is my code:

```
struct ConversationsSection: View {

@State private var isShowingDeleteActions = false

let items = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]

var body: some View {
    List(items, id: \.self) { item in
        Text(item)
            .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                Button(role: .destructive) {
                    isShowingDeleteActions = true
                    print("Trying to delete: " + item)
                } label: {
                    Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                }
            }
            .confirmationDialog("Delete item?", isPresented: $isShowingDeleteActions) {
                Button("Confirm Delete", role: .destructive) {
                    print("Actually deleting: " + item)
                    isShowingDeleteActions = false
                }
            }
    }
}
```

}

The output is:

```
Trying to delete: Two
Actually deleting: Four
Trying to delete: Five
Actually deleting: Three
```

So I swipe an item and `confirmationDialog` is presented. But inside `confirmationDialog` another item is passed. Why is that?

Answer (score 10):

I think of it this way: you have a `confirmationDialog` modifier inside your ForEach loop, so there are multiple confirmation dialogs whose presentation is controlled by a single `$isShowingDeleteActions` state variable. When that happens, SwiftUI can't reliably show the dialog from the instance of the loop that sets the state variable – so it might end up showing a *different* dialog, and one whose `item` value is different.

I get how frustrating it is!

One workaround would be to move the confirmationDialog out of the loop altogether, so there'll only ever be one modifier using `$isShowingDeleteActions`. The snag there is that there's no longer a direct reference to `item`, but we could compensate by keeping a reference in a second state variable:

```swift
struct ConversationsSection: View {

@State private var isShowingDeleteActions = false
@State private var itemToDelete: Item? = nil

var body: some View {
    List(items, id: \.self) { item in
        Text(item)
            .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                Button(role: .destructive) {
                    itemToDelete = item
                    isShowingDeleteActions = true
                } label: {
                    Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                }
            }
    }
    .confirmationDialog("Delete item?", isPresented: $isShowingDeleteActions) {
        Button("Confirm Delete", role: .destructive) {
            if let item = itemToDelete {
                print("Actually deleting: " + item)
                isShowingDeleteActions = false
                itemToDelete = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This definitely works. Thank you.

Holding the value of `itemToDelete` inside another variable until the user confirms deletion is not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Your explanation of multiple `confirmationDialog`s makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Is there a workaround for iPad? The solution works, but now the `confirmationDialog`is always attached to the `List`and not to the correct item inside the `List`.

Comment: @Esera If you move the contents of the row into a separate custom view, effectively making your list `List { MyCustomRow(item: $0) }`, you can move the confirmationDialog into that custom view.

Answer (score 5):

The solution from Scott works fine, but when you want to show the `confirmationDialog` on an iPad, the attachment is off (as it is now using the List as attachment). See the screenshot below:

[image: iPad screenshot of attachment problem]

You can fix this by extracting the `Text` together with its modifiers and the `@State` property into a new view like follows:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ItemView: View {
    
    @State private var isShowingDeleteActions = false
    
    var item: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(item)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                Button(role: .destructive) {
                    isShowingDeleteActions = true
                    print("Trying to delete: " + item)
                } label: {
                    Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                }
            }
            .confirmationDialog("Delete item?", isPresented: $isShowingDeleteActions) {
                Button("Confirm Delete", role: .destructive) {
                    print("Actually deleting: " + item)
                    isShowingDeleteActions = false
                }
            }
    }
}

struct ConversationsSection: View {

    let items = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(items, id: \.self) { item in
                ItemView(item: item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of this:

[image: iPad screenshot, where the attachment is correct]

Comment: You saved my day!!!! I had so much ugly code with `.alert` with extra @State for managing data to be deleted. I can finally remove my ugly code. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: The shown solution has been working in iOS/iPadOS 15, but no longer on iOS/iPadOS 16/16.1. It seems it does not correctly store the isShowindDeleteActions state in iOS 16. Anybody running this successfully on iOS 16+?

Answer (score 2):

2 ways:

1. put "@State private var isPresented", ".swipeActions" and ".confirmationDialog" into list item, just like [Esera's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71046693/12668737). But there is a problem, confirmationDialog often popover and disappear in a second, then popvoer when swipeActions before trash button clicked. After some research, I found it's because swipeActions-.destructive button. use .none instead, everything is fine. see ConfirmationDialog0.
2. use @State private var selectedMessage: Int? = nil, set it in swipeActions, use it in confirmationDialog. Problem is this confirmationDialog [for whole list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLlX9.png), not [for a list item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPlUO.png), just like [Esera's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71046693/12668737).

check my test code:

```
struct ConfirmationDialog: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ConfirmationDialog3()
            ConfirmationDialog0()
            ConfirmationDialog1()
            ConfirmationDialog2()
        }
    }
}

struct ConfirmationDialog3: View {
    @State private var messages: [Int] = (0..<5).map { $0 }
    @State private var confirmationShown = false
    @State private var selectedMessage: Int? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(messages, id: \.self) { message in
                    Text("\(message)")
                        .swipeActions {
                            Button(
                                role: .destructive,
                                action: {
                                    selectedMessage = message
                                    confirmationShown = true
                                }
                            ) {
                                Image(systemName: "trash")
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("YEAH!")
            .confirmationDialog(
                "Are you sure?",
                isPresented: $confirmationShown,
                titleVisibility: .visible,
                presenting: selectedMessage
            ) { message in
                Button("Yes, delete: \(message)") {
                    withAnimation {
                        messages = messages.filter { $0 != message }
                    }
                }.keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)
                Button("No", role: .cancel) {}
            } message: { message in
                Text("\(message)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ConfirmationDialog0: View {
    @State private var messages: [Int] = (0..<5).map { $0 }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(messages, id: \.self) { message in
                    itemView0(message: message) { _ in
                        withAnimation {
                            messages = messages.filter { $0 != message }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("WRONG if .destructive!")
        }
    }
}

struct itemView0: View {
    @State private var confirmationShown = false
    let message: Int
    let onDelete: (Int) -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(message)")
            .swipeActions {
                Button(
                    role: .none,//.destructive,
                    action: { confirmationShown = true }
                ) {
                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                }
                .tint(Color.red)
            }
            .confirmationDialog(
                "Are you sure?",
                isPresented: $confirmationShown,
                titleVisibility: .visible,
                presenting: message
            ) { message in
                Button("Yes, delete: \(message)") {
                    onDelete(message)
                }.keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)

                Button("No", role: .cancel) {}
            } message: { message in
                Text("\(message)")
            }
    }
}

struct ConfirmationDialog1: View {
    @State private var messages: [Int] = (0..<5).map { $0 }
    @State private var confirmationShown = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(messages, id: \.self) { message in
                    Text("\(message)")
                        .swipeActions {
                            Button(
                                role: .destructive,
                                action: { confirmationShown = true }
                            ) {
                                Image(systemName: "trash")
                            }
                        }
                        .confirmationDialog(
                            "Are you sure?",
                            isPresented: $confirmationShown,
                            titleVisibility: .visible,
                            presenting: message
                        ) { message in
                            Button("Yes, delete: \(message)") {
                                withAnimation {
                                    messages = messages.filter { $0 != message }
                                }
                            }.keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)

                            Button("No", role: .cancel) {}
                        } message: { message in
                            Text("\(message)")
                        }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("WRONG!")
        }
    }
}

struct ConfirmationDialog2: View {
    @State private var showingConfirmation = false
    @State private var backgroundColor = Color.white
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(height: 100)
            .background(backgroundColor)
            .onTapGesture {
                showingConfirmation = true
            }
            .confirmationDialog("Change background", isPresented: $showingConfirmation) {
                Button("Red") { backgroundColor = .red }
                Button("Green") { backgroundColor = .green }
                Button("Blue") { backgroundColor = .blue }
                Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) { }
            } message: {
                Text("Select a new color")
            }
    }
}

struct ConfirmationDialog_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ConfirmationDialog()
    }
}
```